# MySQL - Query becomes slow when combining WHERE and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting, indexing

I have a MySQL (v8.0.30) table that stores trades, the schema is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `log_fill` (
 `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `orderId` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
 `clientOrderId` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
 `symbol` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
 `executionId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `executionSide` tinyint NOT NULL COMMENT '0 = long, 1 = short',
 `executionSize` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
 `executionPrice` decimal(21,8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `executionTime` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
 `executionValue` decimal(21,8) NOT NULL,
 `executionFee` decimal(13,8) NOT NULL,
 `feeAsset` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
 `positionSizeBeforeFill` decimal(21,8) DEFAULT NULL,
 `apiKey` int NOT NULL,
 `side` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reconciled` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `executionId` (`executionId`,`executionSide`),
 KEY `apiKey` (`apiKey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6522695 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

As you can see, there's a BTREE index on the column `apiKey` which stands for a user, this way I can quickly retrieve all trades for a specific user.
My goal is a query that returns `positionSizeBeforeFill + executionSize` for the last record, given an `apiKey` and a `symbol`. So I wrote the following:

```
SELECT positionSizeBeforeFill + executionSize 
FROM log_fill 
WHERE apiKey = 90 AND symbol = 'ABCD'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

However the execution is extremely slow (around 100ms). I've noticed that running either `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` (and not both together) drastically reduces execution time. For example

```
SELECT positionSizeBeforeFill + executionSize 
FROM log_fill 
WHERE apiKey = 90 AND symbol = 'ABCD'
```

only takes 220 microseconds to execute. The number of records after filtering by apiKey and symbol is 388.

Similarly,

```
SELECT positionSizeBeforeFill + executionSize 
FROM log_fill 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

takes 26 microseconds (on a 3 million records table).
All in all, separately running `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` takes microseconds of execution, when I combine them we scale up to milliseconds (around 1000x more).

Running `EXPLAIN` on the slow query it turns out it has to examine 116032 rows.

I tried to create a temporary table hoping for MySQL to perform sorting only on the filtered records, but the outcome is the same. Was wondering whether the problem might be the index (whose cardinality is 203), but how can it be the case when WHERE alone takes very little time? I could not find similar cases on other questions or forums. I think I just fail at understanding how InnoDB selects data, I thought it would first filter by WHERE and then perform ORDER BY on the filtered rows. How can I improve this? Thanks!

Edit: The `EXPLAIN` statement on the slow query returns

```
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | log_fill_tmp | NULL       | ref  | apiKey        | apiKey | 4       | const | 116032 |    10.00 | Using where; Backward index scan |
```

The query with `WHERE` only

```
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | log_fill_tmp | NULL       | ref  | apiKey        | apiKey | 4       | const | 116032 |    10.00 | Using where |
```

The query with `ORDER BY` only on the full table

```
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra               |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | log_fill_tmp | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 2503238 |   100.00 | Backward index scan |
```

Comment: Note, when I say 'execution time' I refer to the execution time reported when running the query in phpMyAdmin with profiling enabled.

Comment: Please show us the `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Added the explain output (no worries about the incorrect table name, it's the same I was talking about in the question). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also the `EXPLAIN` of the other 2 queries could be helpful :)

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Added both of them. Thanks.

Comment: Does `SHOW WARNINGS` give additional info?

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara I get "@@profiling' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release." (code 1287).

Comment: In my opinion, "profiling" has always been useless.

Answer (score 1):

26 microseconds for *any* query against a 3-million-row table implies that you have the Query cache enabled.  Please rerunning your timings with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.  (Even milliseconds would be suspicious.)  Were all 3M rows returned?  Shoveling that many rows probably takes more than a second under any circumstances.

Meanwhile, to speed up the first two queries, add

```
INDEX(symbol, apikey, id)
```

`EXPLAIN` gives only approximate (eg, 116032) counts.  A "cardinality" of 203 is also just an estimate, but it is used by the Optimizer in *some* situations.  Please get the exact count just to check that there really are *any* rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM log_fill 
    WHERE apiKey = 90 AND symbol = 'ABCD'
```

With the `ORDER BY id DESC`, it will scan the entire B+Tree what holds the data.  As it says, it will do a 'Backward index scan'.  However, since the "index" is the `PRIMARY KEY` and the PK is clustered with the data, it is really referring to the data's BTree.

The EXPLAIN for the first query decided that the indexes were not useful enough for `WHERE`; instead it avoided the sort (`ORDER BY`) by doing the Backward full table scan, same as the 3rd query.  (And ignored any rows that did not match the WHERE.

Comment: There is something I have not understood in those plans: the `key` field of the `EXPLAIN` output is set to `apiKey`, therefore I thought that the index would be used. But in the `Extra` field, it simply says `Using where`, without mentioning the index for the `apiKey`. Why is that? Thank you.

Comment: With the initial settings (old indices) and `SQL_NO_CACHE`, the query with `ORDER BY` on the full table took 45 microseconds for execution. Note that by execution time I mean the one reported by phpMyAdmin under execution, I don't know if that's a standard or just something they came up with. Reported that metric because it was shown to be the bottleneck. The number of rows for the last query is 388.

Comment: @DamiToma - Did is spell out "microsecond" or did it say just "ms"?

Comment: @RickJames it is microsecond indeed (μs, Greek mu that stands for micro)

Comment: @DamiToma - Hmmm..  I don't think I have ever seen 45us for the _elapsed_ time of a query.  Please provide the context, even it has to be a screenshot.

Comment: @RickJames I'm really unsure about how they calculate the execution time, but I can ensure the query was order of magnitude slower without the new index. I've launched the process on production and it doesn't have a problem now while it got the database stuck before.

Answer (score 0):

I added a composite index on `(apiKey, symbol)` and now the query runs in as little as 0.2ms. In order to reduce the creation time for the index I reduce the number of records from 3M to 500K and the gain in time is about 97%, I believe it's going to be more on the full table. I thought using just the `apiKey` index it would first filter out by user, then by symbol, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: The order of the columns in the `WHERE` does matter; the order in the `INDEX` does matter.  However, when both are tested with `=`, it does not matter.

Comment: With an adequate index and not more rows being _returned_, the size of the table should not matter.  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames 2GB RAM and 1GB buffer size (on AWS RDS)

Comment: 1G/2G is tight.  Was there any "swapping"?

Comment: Also, run each timing test twice -- else caching of the data in the buffer_pool mak cloud the results.  (It sounds like the data is bigger than the buffer_pool, thereby leading to I/O in some cases, caching in other cases.)

Comment: @RickJames I've run all tests dozens of times. On RDS there is swapping, however the same results happen in localhost where the pool size is 1GB and 24GB RAM.